# Convert jQuery line to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some HTML code which I am using on a popup which contains an image, some text, and a button which closes the popup.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="popupHuawei">
  <h2 id="titlePopup">
    *Title here*
  </h2>
  <img class="huaweiPopupImg" src="imgHere">
  <div class="popupContentArea">
    <div class="popupText">
      *Text here*
    </div>
    </br>
  </div>
  <a class="lesMer" href="Link">*Link text*
  </a>
</div>
```

And originally, the button I moved, is outside the entire structure I just posted, but I needed it to be inside #popupHuawei, so I used this code to do so:

```
$(".dy-lb-close").appendTo("#popupHuawei");
```

How to move this button with vanilla JavaScript instead of jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library.

Comment: Yeah, but JavaScript is faster, as I've read many places online. Plus I've been told to prioritize JavaScript over using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
document.querySelector('#popupHuawei').appendChild(document.querySelector('.dy-lb-close')
```

Here's a link to official documentation of [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!